# Extract specific column (by name) from all csv's in working directory in R

Tags: r

I am creating a script that needs to read in all csv files in the working directory, then pull out all values from the "item_number" and "sale_price" columns and put these all into one dataframe. I am currently using the below to read all csv's.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

The issue I have is that I get different names for my data in R each time I run this code (as the working directory is constantly updated with different csv's). So how do I extract the data from the variables mentioned above from all of the csv's that have been read in without calling on them specifically by name?

Note that this is done in a completely fresh environment in R so if there's any way to just read **all** objects and extract those columns then that would work I assume?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: try `select` function.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against using `assign`. This will create a dataframe that with two columns and all the data from the csv's. I guessed on the data type for initializing the dataframe.

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
df <- data.frame(item_number=numeric(0), sale_price=numeric(0))
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
     tmp <- read.csv(temp[i])
     df <- rbind(df, tmp[, c("item_number", "sale_price")]
}
```

Comment: Thank you emiliman5. This answer works perfectly and also made the most sense to me (being fairly new to R).

Comment: lapply is the more "R" way to do this. But from a learning perspective I like to try to get the original code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
lst <- lapply(temp, function(x) read.csv(x)[, "your_column_name"])
```

This will store entries in column `"your_column_name"` for all files in a `list`. Then you can either `cbind` those entries, or process them with `lapply`/`sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

similar to @Maurits + `rbind` call:

```
# example data:
# dir.create("csv")
# cnames <- c("id", "index", "treatment", "item_number", "sale_price")
# fls <- lapply(1:10, function(i) matrix(rep(i, 5), nrow = 1, dimnames = list(1, cnames)))
# lapply(1:length(fls), function(i) write.csv(x[[i]], sprintf("./csv/file%s.csv", i)))
# dir("csv", pattern = ".csv", full.names = T)
# [1] "csv/file1.csv"  "csv/file10.csv" "csv/file2.csv"  "csv/file3.csv" 
# [5] "csv/file4.csv"  "csv/file5.csv"  "csv/file6.csv"  "csv/file7.csv" 
# [9] "csv/file8.csv"  "csv/file9.csv"
```

Main part:

```
pth <- dir("csv", pattern = ".csv", full.names = T)
do.call(rbind, lapply(pth, function(i) read.csv(i)[,c("item_number", "sale_price")]))

#   item_number sale_price
#1            1          1
#2            9          9
#3           10         10
#4            2          2
#5            3          3
#6            4          4
#7            5          5
#8            6          6
#9            7          7
#10           8          8
```